# How can i return a float from an a string of numbers?

Tags: javascript, int, parsefloat

I have a string of numbers when i do svg.getAttribute("d") in the console:

"-0.05990783410138251,0.13594470046082952,-0.06912442396313362,0.14976958525345618,-0.07603686635944701,0.15668202764976957,-0.08755760368663595,0.16589861751152069,-0.09677419354838718,0.16820276497695852,-0.10599078341013829,0.16820276497695852,-0.12211981566820279,0.16820276497695852,-0.13594470046082957,0.16820276497695852,-0.14055299539170513,0.16820276497695852,-0.14516129032258068,0.16589861751152069,-0.1474654377880184"

I want this to be converted to a float so i did parseFloat(svg.getAttribute("d")) but all i get is the first number back:

-0.05990783410138251

How can i get all the numbers?

Thanks

Comment: You can't convert a string of number**s**, plural, to "a float", singular, unless you pick one of the numbers and ignore the rest. If your desired result is an array of numbers please [edit] the question to say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can get an array of float values as follows:

```js
const values = '-0.05990783410138251,0.13594470046082952,-0.06912442396313362,0.14976958525345618,-0.07603686635944701,0.15668202764976957,-0.08755760368663595,0.16589861751152069,-0.09677419354838718,0.16820276497695852,-0.10599078341013829,0.16820276497695852,-0.12211981566820279,0.16820276497695852,-0.13594470046082957,0.16820276497695852,-0.14055299539170513,0.16820276497695852,-0.14516129032258068,0.16589861751152069,-0.1474654377880184';

const floats = values.split(',').map(parseFloat);

console.log(floats);
```

Comment: It should be safe to say `.map(parseFloat)` shouldn't it? (Unlike `.map(parseInt)`, which doesn't do the right thing.)

Answer (score 1):

You can first split the string by ',' using `split()` function and then can apply `parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to an array of strings first, then you can parse each of them individually. Something like this:

```
var str = svg.getAttribute("d");
var strNums = str.split(',');
var nums = strNums.map(function (num) {
    return parseFloat(num);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const numArray = thatStringOfNumbers.split(',').map((num) => parseFloat(num))
```

Comment: Always give some explanation about your answer. Otherwise it will treat as a low quality post and may be deleted.